# Full-height flex item with height set to 0

Tags: css

I have the following code as working on development with flexbox.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

#item1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 0;
}

#item2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

#item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div id="item1"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div id="item2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div id="item3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that setting `flex-grow: 1` would take the remaining space of its parent. However, the property `height` seems to have no effect whatever its value is.

Answer (score 0):

Reason being your flex-direction is set to column, which mean the flex-grow reacts from top to bottom, so the flex-grow responding to the height instead of width.

another question is, why flex-direction is column, but width is filled up, because it is a <div> displayed as block, the width is auto filled by `display: block;`

Comment: So, if an element (its parent has property `flex-direction: column`) has been set flex-grow to any non-zero value, the property `height` would be ignored? Thank a lot.

Comment: No, it will be considered as long as it's minor than parent's height. In your case, if you set parent's height to `auto', parent height will increase to fill child's height (making 'flex-grow' a non-sense)

Comment: @Sir_Faenor Thank for your response. I've updated the description in order to express my question clearly. In new case, I created three items with different `height`, but all of them would expand to full-height of parent.

Answer (score -1):

you are using flex-grow that’s why. have a look on this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp

Comment: So, the property height setting to such an element would be ignored? Thank a lot.

Comment: you need to look for the flex-grow property. I’ll recommend you to have a look on this.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64748435/1095913 (down here) is right, solution is: `flex-grow: 0`;

Here's another reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Comment: In this situation, setting property height seems not to work correctly, such as setting `height: 600px` in the above code (https://codepen.io/yujie0505/pen/pobxrbq). Do you have any idea about it? Thank a lot.